# Perforce: merge/integrate a release stream to the parent virtual stream

Tags: merge, perforce, perforce-integrate

I have a main stream and a child virtual stream (say ProjVirt whose parent is Main). I created a release stream say rel1.0 from the ProjVirt stream - so that the changes can migrate from rel1.0 to ProjVirt.

Even the graph view shows the green merge arrow going from rel1.0 to ProjVirt (saying a merge is possible), but I cannot merge the changes from rel1.0 to the parent virtual stream. I keep getting the following warning:

```
p4 merge -c 324065 -S //depot/rel1.0 -P //depot/ProjVirt -s //depot/Main/myProj/...
    no files opened
    1 warning reported
    No target file(s) in both client and branch view.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that p4 merge take a `-s` parameter according to [this documentation](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/cmdref/merge.html)

`p4 merge -c 324065 -S //depot/rel1.0` would merge from parent to child (this is the default direction).

If you want to merge in the other direction, you have to use the reverse syntax *-r* :

```
 p4 merge -c 324065 -r -S //depot/rel1.0
```

I don't think you need anything else as target, because p4 can deduce the parent stream automatically from your stream config.

I think the original error message was due to the fact that changelist 324065 has no file in parent stream, but rather files in rel1.0. And since you were merging from parent, p4 found no file to merge.

Comment: Great suggestions! Also, make sure you are switched to the target stream (e.g., `p4 client -s -S //depot/Main`) before issuing `p4 merge`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the command line was generated by the P4V client. I switched to the target stream, right clicked on the parent folder and selected 'Merge/Integrate to <stream>' and got the error in the console. Does that mean my P4V client is not upto date? The version says '2015 February 18'.

Comment: @raghu my link points to a 2012 version, so maybe my informations are out of date